# How to get img inside a particular div using JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have to get all the image tags ids inside a particular div. How can I get that using JQuery?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
var arraysOfIds = $('#particularDivId img').map(function(){
                       return this.id;
                   }).get();

// arraysOfIds has now all the id's, access it as arraysOfIds[0], arraysOfIds[1]....
```

Comment: Ahh, cool. I've learned something new with the .map() feature. Though, looking at the documentation, why do you need the .get() call at the end. I just tried your code without it and it worked fine. Newbie wanting to learn.

Answer (score 10):

Rough guess, but try:

```
var imgIds = new Array();

$("div#divID img").each(function(){
    imgIds.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

You haven't given the name of the `div`, but I've used `divId` as the id of the div. Simply change that to suite your needs.

Comment: You should probably use an array, not a string.

Answer (score 9):

Use a child selector. So your saying I want all of the child 'img' elements of div #myDiv

```
$("#myDiv > img").css("border", "3px double red");
```

http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Comment: I wanted this to work, when I replaced $('img').doStuff(); with $("#contents > img").doStuff(); it no longer does stuff. I tried single quotations and div#contents as well.

Comment: My solution was to use the descendent selector not child. [link](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

Comment: This DOES NOT select all of the child img elements of a div but simply the direct descendants.

Answer (score 3):

```
function textOnly() {
            jQuery('#dvContent img').each(function () {
                jQuery(this).css('display', 'none');
            });
        }
```