# I want to get image source from slider?

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow

I want get current image source from slider. when its slides that image source has to be captured in text box but it is taking only first image src and not taking the subsequent images. I am using pgwSlideshow plugin..

HTML code,

```
<div class="cartBgclr">
    <a href="#cart" onclick="addToCart(this)">
        <div class="enqry-cart enqry-cart1 pull-left">
            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart pull-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span class="pull-left">add to enquiry cart</span>
            <input type="text" name="image-path" class="image-path" value="" />
        </div>
        <h4 style="display:none;">Sandstone</h4>
    </a>
            </div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <ul class="pgwSlideshow add-to-cart">
            <li><img src="images/sandstone/sandstone1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/sandstone/sandstone2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/sandstone/sandstone3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/sandstone/sandstone4.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/sandstone/sandstone5.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/sandstone/sandstone6.jpg" alt="" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="pd20"></div>
</div>
```

jquery code,

```
var imgSrc = $('.pgwSlideshow').find('img').attr('src');
console.log(imgSrc);
```

Comment: Posible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021152/how-to-get-img-inside-a-particular-div-using-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the attribute using setInterval() method.
Since slideshow default interval duration is 3s, set 3000ms delay to setInterval

```
setInterval(function(){
  var imgSrc = $(".ps-selected > img").attr("src");
  console.log(imgSrc);
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that in jQuery, some methods work on arrays in get mode, and others work only on single elements. The `attr` method is one such method, the documentation states:

> Get the value of an attribute for the **first** element in the set of matched elements.

(emphasis my own)

So in this example it will only ever return the `src` of the first element in the set returned by `find`.

The [pgwSlideshow](http://pgwjs.com/pgwslideshow/) plugin sets all slides except the 'current' slide to be `display: none`, so you should be able to filter by this to get the `src` for the 'current' slide, something like:

```
var imgSrc = $('.pgwSlideshow').find('li').filter(':visible').find('img').attr('src');
```

You could also use the plugin's own API for this - it has a `getCurrentSlide` method, which returns the index of the current slide. If you used this in the `afterSlide` function, you should be able to get the `src` of the current image.

Comment: I'm not able to find a hosted/CDN version of the plugin, so I can't put together a CodePen for testing. Try logging `$('.pgwSlideshow').find('li').filter(':visible')` - does this contain anything?